# From client logs, I have retrieved the folder ID causing a sync issue. How do i find the associated folder for this ID?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have sync issues on Outlook and have identified the folder ID causing the issue. My account is Exchange on premise 2016. What Powershell commands do I run to find the associated folder name?

Comment: I think https://superuser.com/ will be a more suitable place for such question

Comment: Can you post the ID, or something representative of it?  Depending on the format you may be able to filter the results of Get-MailboxFolderStatistics to find the actual folder.